# Erro ao usar Random em JAVA

Tags: java, random

Quando executo esse código:

```java
public class main 
{
    static boolean terminar = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long init  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        BruteForce(true, true, "a123", 10, 10000);

        long end  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        long diff = end - init;
        System.out.println("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
    }
    public static String BruteForce(boolean numeros, boolean letras, String busca,int maxCaracteres,  int limite)
    {
        ArrayList<String> old = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> caracteres = new ArrayList<String>();

        Random rand = new Random();

        String[] todos = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"
                          , "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "k", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
                          , "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"
                          , "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "'", "!", "@", "#", "$", "£", "%", "¢", "¨", "¬", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-"
                          , "+", "=", "§", "/", ".", "[", "]", "`", "´", "{", "}", "º", "^", "~", "<", ">", ":", ";", "?", "°", "ª",
                          "|", "¹", "²", "³"};

        for(int j = 0; j < todos.length; j++)
        {
            caracteres.add(todos[j]);
        }

        String combinacao = "";
        int quantCaracteres = 1;
        int stop = todos.length * quantCaracteres;

        while(old.size() != stop)
        {   
            for(int i = 0; i < quantCaracteres; i++)
            {
                int randomico = rand.nextInt(todos.length + 1);

                combinacao = "" + combinacao + todos[randomico];
            }

            if(combinacao.equals(busca))
            {
                return combinacao;
            }

            if(!old.contains(combinacao))
            {
                old.add(combinacao);
                System.out.println("Size:" + old.size() + " Stop:" + (stop -1) + " Todos:" + todos.length);
                System.out.println(combinacao);
            }

            combinacao = "";

            if(old.size() == stop)
            {
                quantCaracteres++;
            }
        }

        return "Nada";
    }
}
```

Ele dá esse erro

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 107
at me.lordlokon.main.BruteForce(main.java:49)
at me.lordlokon.main.main(main.java:14)
```

A linha 49 é essa:

```java
combinacao = "" + combinacao + todos[randomico];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veja isso:

```
        int randomico = rand.nextInt(todos.length + 1);

        combinacao = "" + combinacao + todos[randomico];
```

De acordo com [os javadocs do método `nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Retorna um pseudoaleatório, uniformemente distribuído valor int entre 0 (inclusive) e o valor especificado (exclusive)

Ou seja, vai ser entre 0 e `todos.length`.

Aconntece que a última posição do array `todos` é a posição `todos.length - 1`. Quando o número gerado for `todos.length`, vai dar um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

O que você queria era isso:

```
        int randomico = rand.nextInt(todos.length);

        combinacao = "" + combinacao + todos[randomico];
```

Ou seja, é só tirar o `+ 1` do código.

E por fim, uma dica que não tem nada a ver com os números aleatórios: Siga as convenções de nomenclatura da linguagem. O nome da classe `main` deveria começar com letra maiúscula e o nome do método `BruteForce` deveria começar com letra minúscula.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas.